# Trying to position the text in my nav

Tags: html, css

So I'm simply trying to get the text in each line item to be position at the bottom of the square rather than stuck at the top. Here is a screenshot of what my nav looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNgqr.jpg

And here is my code:

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>       
                <li><a href="supplies.html">Supplies</a></li>
                <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>




#nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #FF5252;
    font-family: sans-serif, Georgia;
    border: 5px solid white;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
}

#nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF5252;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ww0w5b4z/).

Add this attribute:

```
line-height:80px;
```

To the Class:

```
#nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF5252;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `list-style: none` to `#nav ul li` and `line-height: 50px`(should be the same as `height` of the `a` element, if you want to center the text vertically)  to `#nav ul li a`.

### [Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/cad0cecd37a0375f64ec)

```
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 145px;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF5252;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use height; instead use appropriate padding-top.

```
#nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF5252;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-top or
line-height in **nav ul li a**